# Incorrect results with IN statement in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mariadb, aggregate-functions

I have encountered quite strange issue with my MariaDB instance when using IN statement.

For example, if I need info on some aggregated product volumes vending devices sell I execute a query as follows:

```
SELECT
SUM( l.volume_given ) AS volume,
COUNT( l.id ) AS sessions,
l.order AS container,
MIN( dev.NAME ) AS NAME,
MIN( dev.address ) AS address,
dev.id AS id
FROM
devices AS dev
JOIN my_logs AS l ON dev.id = l.device_id
WHERE
l.created_at >= '2020-08-31 21:00:00'
AND l.created_at <= '2020-10-21 21:00:00'
AND l.water_type = 0
AND l.device_id IN (*some 20 IDs here*)
GROUP BY container
ORDER BY sessions DESC;
```

What is strange is that for example for ID = 114 there I get only 4 rows for this device out of 232 total rows. However, if I execute the same query but with

```
AND l.device_id = 114
```

I get 44 rows for this ID which is its real result.

What I tried was to:

1. skip the JOIN stuff and use only `my_logs` table;
2. try different date intervals;
3. try similar queries on other tables.

No difference with all this stuff.

Do you have any ideas what to check?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You are aggregating by `container`.  And your `group by` columns are inconsistent with the `select` columns.  I'm surprised the query works.

Comment: Actually it is slightly modified (by JOIN) query from backend Ruby app where it works somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want the `id` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY l.order, dev.id
```

It is a golden rule in SQL that all non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause should be repeated in the `GROUP BY` clause (unless they are functionally dependent on another column that belongs to that clause - but that's another story).

MySQL has been lax about that in early versions, causing somehow counter-intuitive behaviors that are then hard to debug if you don't have that rule in mind. Make sure to always enable sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, so such problems are treated as syntax errors.

Note that this modified `GROUP BY` clause uses the actual column names rather than their alias; that's standard SQL as well (while MySQL allows otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Turning it inside out may speed it up:

```
SELECT  l2.volume, l2.sessions, l2.container,
        dev.NAME, dev.address, dev.id
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  l.device_id, l.order AS container,
                SUM( l.volume_given ) AS volume,
                COUNT(*) AS sessions
            FROM  logs AS l
            WHERE  l.created_at >= '2020-08-31 21:00:00'
              AND  l.created_at <= '2020-10-21 21:00:00'
              AND  l.water_type = 0
              AND  l.device_id IN (*some 20 IDs here*)
            GROUP BY  l.device_id, container 
    ) AS l2
    JOIN  devices AS dev  ON dev.id = l2.device_id
    ORDER BY  l2.sessions DESC
```

And it may fix the count(*) overcount.

I recommend

```
INDEX(water_type, device_id)
INDEX(water_type, created_at)
```